# create directory is not creating a file folder c#

Tags: c#, directory, create-directory

I'm trying to create a file folder through the program to hold pdfs that I will later generate. I am doing so in my local and internal server, using the same code to do so:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(pathName))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
```

It works fine if it goes to local, but when I send it to the internal path the

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(pathNameInternal);
```

creates a file, not an actual file folder which is causing errors later in the code when it tries to access that named folder.

I have no idea why it is creating a file, anyone have any ideas?

Code from comment:

```
theOut = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UserDownloads"; 

Directory.CreateDirectory(theOut + "\\" + DBName); 

if (copyInternal == true) 
{ 
    theOutInternal = @"\\192.168.2.40\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\UserDownloads"; 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(theOutInternal); 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(theOutInternal + "\\" + DBName); 
}
```

Comment: It cannot. You’d have to provide a [mcve] for anyone to verify this. Are you sure there’s not some other part of code creating a file? Did you add a breakpoint here, check that there’s no such file, then step over this line and see that it created a file?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong- but you don't need that `If` statement to check if it already exists. I believe `CreateDirectory()` does the check already.

Comment: Directory.CreateDirectory will not create a file. The issue is likely when you later use pathNameInternal you ignore a missing trailing slash when building a path. (Path.Combine() will help with this)

Comment: Try excluding the file name from the path (i.e `C:\users\Me\file.txt` to `C:\users\Me\ `) . This should create the directory, then save the file after the directory is created with `pathNameInternal + fileName`

Comment: You were right about the if statement, it was unnecessary. However I still get an error. I have used breakpoints and know that it is exactly the create directory line that is creating a file.

Comment: theOut = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UserDownloads";                        
          Directory.CreateDirectory(theOut + "\\" + DBName);                       
                        if (copyInternal == true)
                        {
                            theOutInternal = @"\\192.168.2.40\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\UserDownloads";                       
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(theOutInternal);                                                  
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(theOutInternal + "\\" + DBName);
                        }

Comment: In the future, don't put code in comments.  It is too hard to read.